# Resolving ambiguities in an expression using LL(1) grammar

Tags: parsing, grammar, ll-grammar, left-recursion

I need to construct a parser for an expression which is allowed to have only 2 operators (AND & OR) and such that both operators cannot be presenet in a enclosing paranthesis.

**Eg1:**

```
(A AND B OR C) --> invalid
(A AND (B OR C)) --> valid
```

**Eg2:**

```
(A AND (B OR C) OR D) --> invalid
((A AND (B OR C)) OR D) --> valid
(A AND ((B OR C) OR D)) --> valid
```

**Please note:** I'm very new to this. I had tried to attempt this using LL(1) parser by following a few online tutorials. Here is what I've achieved so far.

```
E -> F E'
E' -> OR F E'
E' -> ''
F -> G F'
F' -> AND G F'
F' -> ''
G -> ( E )
G -> id
```

The above grammar rules checks whether I have only the valid operators & parenthesis but doesn't not identify the ambiguity problem. I'm not expecting a solution here but I just wanna know if I'm on the right track. Because in one of the tutorial the tutor had mentioned that `LL(1)` parser will not work if there is more than one lookup for a terminal symbol. I know that I haven't encountered such a situation yet but will I (particularly when generating the rules for resolving the ambiguity)???

**Edit1**

```
E -> F E'
E' -> OR F E'
E' -> AND F E'
E' -> ''
F -> ( E )
F -> id
```

**Edit2: Solution**

```
E -> F E'
E' -> and F G
E' -> or F H
E' -> ''
G -> and F G
G -> ''
H -> or F H
H -> ''
F -> ( E )
F -> id
```

Comment: Oops, sorry. Missed an empty production. Anyway, the thing to think about: what goes inside parentheses? It is an expression optionally followed either by a series of ANDs or by a series of ORs. You already have the productions for both types of series, so you just have to put them together correctly.

Comment: Exactly, I had the same idea too and I've updated the question with my new rules. But still I'm missing somewhere...

Comment: Hint: the `E'` at the end of `E' -> OR F E'` allows for `x OR y OR z`.

Comment: Another hint: G and H can't end with the same non-terminal, because they don't have the same possible continuations.

Comment: @rici How about now?

Comment: That looks right to me at a quick glance.

Comment: Thanks a ton!!! :-)